# Longest route of a stream in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, vba, line, rivers

[image]

I have a shapefile with polylines representing rivers all over a region.
In the attached image, there is an example of one river.

The longest route is marked by the two red dots on this river, but it is divided into many polylines especially along this route. I would like to find the total length of this river (and many many others) without having to manually delete all tributaries then merge the longest route.

Is there an efficient method for accomplishing this task? Is it possible to do this task to many rivers at the same time?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 with an ArcInfo license. I have access to VBA, but not Visual Studio.

Comment: I am not sure that the longest route is obvious in your diagram so perhaps you can indicate it a different colour. Are you looking for the two locations in your stream network which are the furthest apart "by river"?

Comment: I have marked it with red dots to make it more clear. I am looking to find the length of the river, which is where the red markings start and end. I want to do this with many other rivers as well, this is only an example. Between those red dots, the polyline is many polylines of varying lengths.

Comment: Your data are not sufficient to obtain answers: you must somehow mark the mouth of the river. The figure provides a nice example: how is the software (or a human being, for that matter) to determine that the mouth is at the bottom and not along the bottom-left tributary? Two natural ways to indicate the mouth are (a) digitize the polygons so that their orientations are in the direction of flow and (b) create a corresponding point exactly at the mouth. Another issue that will occur with detailed data concerns islands: do you want to take the longest or the shortest route around each island?

Comment: There will be islands along the rivers, but let's just say an insignificant amount to make much of a difference. This river polyline was created from a larger dataset where I removed all polylines with a strahler order of 3 or less (headwaters). So technically that last tributary that is marked at the bottom will be the highest order which can be used to determine flow direction.

Comment: My point is that in order to do the calculation automatically you need this additional information available somehow to the software and you need to be specific about which distance you want to compute. (You might still run into difficulties with river deltas where the multiple mouths create problems.)  Precisely how will you make this information available? What will your inputs be?

Comment: How could I mark the mouths of the rivers to avoid this issue?

Comment: The Dissolve tool would work great, once I remove the branches somehow.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to revise it in line with your responses to whuber, please?  I suspect the lack of Answer(s) to your Question is because potential answerers are still not clear what you are asking.